# Push data into another object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I push new values into an existing object?

Basically I get some form data`noteValue` and I have some other data being input to my component `person` which I would like to make part of `noteValue` before I run my save function.

```
let noteValue = form.value;
noteValue.said_by.person_name = this.person.name;
```

This is an example I have working elsewhere but it doesn't seem to work:

```
let exValue = form.value;    
exValue['due_date'].timestamp = this.timestamp;
```

What am I missing? And is this even the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting any error? It will be useful to share the detail of `form`

Comment: If `noteValue` does not have a `said_by` property, it will return an error

Comment: Can you please describe your problem with more detail? What do you want to achieve? What kind of app are you developing? Can you give some code samples?

Comment: is ``due_date`` already a key in the ``exValue``?

Comment: try debugging your code first.
`let noteValue = form.value;
console.log('mynotevalue', noteValue);
noteValue.said_by.person_name = this.person.name;`

check the result of console. by there try modifying the value

Comment: can't understand what you want to ask
what i understand is u have an object and u want to add another property or var to it. So, var noteValue = { value:23,name:"xyz"}; noteValue.personName = "jas"  will give { value:23,name:"xyz",personName:"jas"}

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `spread operator` to create a new object that contains both the `prevState` and the `newData` you have, then replace the `prevState` with the `newState`

`const newState = {...prevState, newData}
prevState = newState;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()`.

`Object.assign()`  Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.

```js
var obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
var obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };
var obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj);
```